# Android SSH Client using paramiko and Kivy, on android app crashes after opening

Tags: python, android, ssh, kivy, buildozer

Hi I have a python Kivy app that is supposted to open a window, ask for ssh details, open a ssh connection, take input and display output. On windows and ubuntu (vm) it runs perfectly fine but after building it with buildozer and runinng on android it shows loading screen for a second and than crashes. I tried everything but I dont know what to do so here is the code.

**main.py**

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import paramiko


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="host: "))
        self.host = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.host)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="port: "))
        self.port = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.port)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="username: "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.username)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="password: "))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.password)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="command: "))
        self.command = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.command)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=32)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.press)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

        self.output = Label(text=" ")
        self.add_widget(self.output)

        self.logged_in = False

    def press(self, instance):
        host, port, username, password, command = self.host.text, self.port.text, self.username.text, self.password.text, self.command.text

        if not self.logged_in:
            self.client.connect(host, int(port), username, password)
        self.logged_in = True

        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        lines = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        self.remove_widget(self.output)
        self.output = Label(text=str(lines))
        self.inside.add_widget(self.output)

        self.host.text, self.port.text, self.username.text, self.password.text, self.command.text = "", "", "", "", ""


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**buildozer.spec**

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = SSHonza

# (str) Package name
package.name = sshonza

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,paramiko

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.0.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

I dont know how the buildozer.spec file schould look like or if the problem is elsewhere.

(sorry for my bad english, I am not native speaker)

Comment: In `buildozer.spec` in requirements add those:
`requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,paramiko`
I recommend installing `kivy 2.0.0` in plugins trough settings in which ever program you are using for coding.

Comment: I tried but stille crashes any more tips/ideas? @GuramiSupatashvili

Comment: Connect your phone to your pc and in project folders terminal run `buildozer android deploy logcat debug`. Make sure `USB DEBUGGING` is enabled in phones developer settings. And then run your app in phone and you should see errors in terminal

Comment: And add `buildozer.spec` in your question. It will be helpful

Comment: Try this: `requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,paramiko==2.7.2`

Comment: added buildozer.spec @GuramiSupatashvili

Comment: Does your app requires wifi?

Comment: how can I do that? (what line of spec file)

Comment: If your app requires wifi do this:
`# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET
android.permissions = INTERNET`

Comment: done everything but got error while building here is log https://pastebin.com/rSBi2LCj

Comment: It's forbidden for me to view this link

Comment: try this https://justpaste.it/2yaea

Comment: go back to this `requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,paramiko`. remove version of paramiko and it should work

Comment: still the same, full log with main.py and buildozer.spec at the top https://justpaste.it/9gifv

Comment: I see you'er using text documet. Am I correct?

Comment: Are you using any other stuff? Like audio file or something else?

Comment: nope just this:

(venv) honnza@honnza-vm:~/Desktop/apk-development/build$ ls
bin  buildozer.spec  main.py
(venv) honnza@honnza-vm:~/Desktop/apk-development/build$

Comment: Try adding this:
`# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,txt`

Comment: still the same, I will try creating new dir with new venv and install it again

Comment: I got the build succesfully but after installing on android, opening app I can see loading screen and after that app still crashes.

Comment: Debug the with command: `buildozer android deploy logcat debug`
The problem should appear there

Comment: I am using VM and if I connect my phone to pc it doesnt show its connected to the vm just the host system windows

Comment: I got adb on windows and here is log.txt of the app crashing  https://jpst.it/2A8md   @GuramiSupatashvili

Answer (score 0):

Making the following changes in the spec file should make the app work.

Change your `requirements` to:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.3.0,paramiko,cryptography,bcrypt,pynacl
```

and set `android.permissions`:

```
# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
```

See the [build option](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions.html#id2) documentation for all the supported syntaxes and properties.